# find a value in a row if it is no longer true in a column R

Tags: r

This should be very simple but it is giving me a hard time in spite of looking.

I have a dataframe with column values a,b,c

```
a   b   c
t1  10  TRUE
t2   9  TRUE
t3   8  FALSE
t4   7  FALSE
t5   6  FALSE
t6   5  TRUE
t7   4  TRUE
t8   3  TRUE
```

I need to get the rows in the data frame where c changes from `TRUE` to `FALSE` or `FALSE` to `TRUE` (rows `t3   8  FALSE` and `t6   5  TRUE`).

Seems like an `ifelse` would do this but I am having trouble figuring out how to do the change part.

Comment: Hi there, since you seem quite new to SO, I would recommend you to read the [**SO about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and also the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how SO works on asking questions and accepting answers.

Comment: What Arun is trying to say is that StackOverflow is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark. You are under absolutely **no** obligation to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Arun and Jordon. Will go and look and make sure I have done this. Thank you. I did read SO about but often things don't stick in old brains. I will try to be attentive to details and I appreciate the comments. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a task for `xor` logical operation. The `xor` operation gives:

```
#       x     y   xor
# 1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Using this, if we take `df$c` and then `xor` with `c(NA, head(df$c, -1))`, the latter of which is a shifted version of `df$c`, then we get:

```
#       x     y   xor
# 1  TRUE    NA    NA
# 2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 6  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 8  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

And here you want those entries that are `TRUE`. So,

```
df[with(df, xor(c, c(NA, head(c, -1))) %in% TRUE), ]

#    a b     c
# 3 t3 8 FALSE
# 6 t6 5  TRUE
```

Even better, we can eliminate the usage of `NA` and therefore `%in%` with:

```
df[with(df, xor(c, c(c[1], head(c, -1)))), ]

#    a b     c
# 3 t3 8 FALSE
# 6 t6 5  TRUE
```

Comment: `which` would be an alternative to `%in% TRUE`

Comment: Well I just discovered you can only click the green arrow on one answer. So I clicked this one since this is the one I will use. I can understand this solution and I learned a new thing xor. Plus this answer was all in one row. But really the other one worked just fine to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `diff` which calculates the difference between one value and the next, because `TRUE` and `FALSE` are just 1 and 0. If you go from `TRUE` to `FALSE` you get -1, if you go from `FALSE` to `TRUE` you get 1, if it's just T-T or F-F it will be 0. You can then use this to subset your dataframe using `which` to select the rows. It boils down to one line (I call your dataframe `df`)...

```
df[ which( diff( df$c ) != 0 ) + 1 , ]
#   a b     c
#   3 t3 8 FALSE
#   6 t6 5  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `rle` example:

```
set.seed(110)
df <- data.frame( a = sample.int(10 , 10 ) , b = sample( c( TRUE , FALSE ) , 10 , repl = TRUE ) )

rles <- rle(df$b)
take <- cumsum(rles$lengths) + 1

df[take[-length(take)], ]
```